# How to cite Stack Overflow surveys

Tags: citations, bibtex

How should I cite the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020)?

*If possible in BibTeX format.*

---

This question was [originally asked in meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315057/how-to-cite-stack-overflow-surveys), but it was closed for being considered off-topic.

Emphasis is mine:

> DO NOT USE this tag unless your question's about the Developer Survey's integration with sites other than Stack Overflow. **Most questions about the annual Stack Overflow Developer Survey should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow**, not here.
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey

This question was also asked in [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407220/how-to-cite-stack-overflow-surveys).

Comment: You cite it like anything else, by its title, author(s)/editor(s), etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. Include this as a footnote.
2. Use [this website](https://www.bibme.org/bibtex/website-citation) to generate website citations for the BibTeX generic citations.

The following is I generated for the Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020.

```
@misc{stack overflow, 
      title={Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020},      
      url={https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020}, 
      journal={Stack Overflow}
     }
```

Comment: +50 (bounty). I think that website that generates BibTeX for webpages is cool, and I was hoping others would suggest more tools like that, but no one did, so I awarded the bounty exactly as I described in the bounty announcement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can

- add a bit more details, following e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3587/34551,
- that the author should be "Stack Overflow" (cf. the readme in [the downloadable database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfGerWeWkcyQ9GX9x20rdSGj7WtEpzBB/view), where attribution needs to be given to "Stack Overflow"),
- that Stack Overflow should be ["protected"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10775/34551) from losing its upper-case, (cf. also [this discussion on institutions as authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162659/34551)),
- that you can infer the publication date from [the announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/27/2020-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/),
- and that you can use `urldate` to refer to the date you last accessed the survey.

This gives:

```
@misc{stackoverflow_survey_2020,
    author={Stack {O}verflow},
    title = {Stack {O}verflow Developer Survey 2020},
    url = {https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020/},
    abstract = {Nearly 65,000 took this comprehensive, annual survey of people who code. Demographics. Most loved, dreaded and wanted technologies. Salary and careers.},
    urldate = {2021-08-18},
    date    = {2020-05-27} 

}
```

Or, if you are using [biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/34551), you can use the `online` entry type:

```
@online{stackoverflow_survey_2020,
    author={Stack {O}verflow},
    title = {Stack {O}verflow Developer Survey 2020},
    url = {https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020/},
    abstract = {Nearly 65,000 took this comprehensive, annual survey of people who code. Demographics. Most loved, dreaded and wanted technologies. Salary and careers.},
    urldate = {2021-08-18},
    date    = {2020-05-27} 
}
```

Comment: Not a bad answer! I like the simplicity of the method suggested in the first answer: An online tool that automatically turns any URL into BibTeX format without any further work for the user to do!